# grandfather of or to two children?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

What do these mean?

1. He's a grandfather **of** two.
2. He's a grandfather **to** two.

Comment: They can both be correct; it depends on what you're trying to convey. *Of* means biologically related. *To* means acting as. (And both are possible at the same time.)

Comment: Google shows both are in use.

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship is biological, it's "of":

"He's a grandfather of two."
"She's the mother of triplets."

If the relationship is metaphorical, it's "to":

"Ralph is 'grandpa' to 75 inmates."
"That dog is the mother to those ducklings."

If the relationship is created, it's either/or:

"He is the husband of/to four wives."
"They are the adoptive parents of/to three siblings." US.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @leopard220 You can highlight the checkmark to accept the answer. Nice to do.

Comment: In BrE using "to" for a biological relationship is completely fine. See e.g. the speech of Maximus Decimus Meridius in Gladiator, where he states he is "father to a murdered son".